# Keras TimeDistributed with multiple Inputs in different shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I've got a pretrained model with multiple inputs which have different shapes. So I can call the model on new inputs that have a matching shape like this:

```
new_output = model([input_1, input2])
```

with

```
input_1.shape = (400, 200)
input_2.shape = (400, 200, 10)
```

I want to reuse the model to train it on a data-series, so my new inputs would have the following shapes:

```
input_1.shape = (100, 400, 200)
input_2.shape = (100, 400, 200, 10)
```

To reuse the model I want to use the `TimeDistributed` layer from Keras like this:

```
output = TimeDistributed(model)([input_1, input_2])
```

This doesn't work because `TimeDistributed` doesn't accept lists as input. All workarounds that I found so far are using merged inputs to solve this problem, but this solution doesn't work in my case because the input shapes are different.

I also tried to use some `Lambda` layers like this:

```
lambda_0 = Lambda(lambda x: x)
lambda_1 = Lambda(lambda x: [TimeDistributed(lambda_0)(x[0]), TimeDistributed(lambda_0)(x[1])])([input_1, input_2])
output = model(lambda_1)
```

But this isn't working because it just uses the `TimeDistributed` on the `lambda_0` but not on the model. Maybe there is a solution with `Lambda` wrappers for this problem or maybe I have to define a custom Keras layer but at the moment I'm stuck with this problem so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does your initial model have one output layer?

Comment: Yes, the inputs are concatenated inside the model and produce one output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily reshape `(?, 400, 200)` to `(?, 400, 200, 1)` and then concatenate the two inputs to have a Tensor of shape `(?, 400, 200, 11)`, then feed this tensor to a `Lambda` layer which is wrapped in a `TimeDistributed` layer and therefore applies your model on each timestep:

```
in1 = Input((400, 200))
in2 = Input((400, 200, 10))

r_in1 = Reshape((400, 200, 1))(in1) # you can also use `K.expand_dims()` in a Lambda layer
concat = concatenate([r_in1, in2])

out_model = TimeDistributed(Lambda(lambda x: model([x[:,:,0], x[:,:,1:]])))(concat)

new_model = Model([in1, in2], [out_model])
```

Comment: This solutions works. In my case I had to adjust the shapes of the layers after splitting them again. Just telling you in case somebody has the same problem ;)
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have a problem with the shapes after using this approach. @Stoney what do you mean you had to adjust the shapes of the layers?

Comment: @SebiSebi It's hard to understand what is wrong without seeing your code. Please ask a new question, providing enough details (i.e. your code, what you expect, full error log, etc.). Then surely people can help you much better.